# How to debug spring-social-showcase?

Tags: spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, spring-social, tcserver

I have downloaded spring-social-showcase project. I can run the project in command prompt using `mvn tomcat:run`. I can browse the project in url typing `http://localhost:8080/spring-social-showcase`. How can I debug the project? I also can not run the project in sts because sts does not show the option Project > Run as > Run on server. Is it possible to run/debug the project through sts? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Import the project as a maven project except general project. Then you can run/debug the project.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd > Go till path of pom > type mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 > and import the project as general project and run on server .